# CodeRush shared sources - Missing file AssemblyVersionInfo.cs

Tags: coderush

I'm opening the CodeRush shared sources, e.g. CR_CommentPainter in Visual Studio 2008 and 2010, but Visual Studio is complaining about missing file. AssemblyVersionInfo.cs

Anyone shed any light ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shared source plugins share a common AssemblyVersionInfo.cs file..

The file itself is held in the shipping **solution folder**. This is the common '**Source**' folder in which all of the shared source projects sit.

Therefore if you're trying to locate the AssemblyVersionInfo.cs file for **CR_CommentPainter** and the project itself is stored in **CodeRush\SOURCES\CR_CommentPainter** then the AssemblyVersionInfo.cs file should be in **CodeRush\SOURCES**

It is entirely possible that you may have chosen to copy the CR_CommentPainter folder elsewhere for experimentation purposes.

If this is the case then you will not have copied the AssemblyVersionInfo.cs file from it's parent folder and as such, visual studio will be unable to find it.

If for any reason this file goes missing, the latest (11.1) version of this code is

---

```
using System.Reflection;
using DevExpress.DXCore.LicenseUtils;

[assembly: AssemblyCompany("Developer Express, Inc")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("IDE Tools for Visual Studio .NET")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright (c) 2003-2011, Developer Express, Inc")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion(DevExpress.DXCore.LicenseUtils.AssemblyInfo.Version)]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion(DevExpress.DXCore.LicenseUtils.AssemblyInfo.FileVersion)]
```

---

.. and it appears currently to only vary from previous versions, by copyright date.